# Triangular numbers patterns

Tags: python

[Question output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOKa2.png)

Write a program that prints out the first n triangular numbers. A triangular
number or triangle number counts the objects that can form an equilateral
triangle, as in the diagram below. The nth triangular number is the number
of dots composing a triangle with n dots on a side. Your program should
produce the following output for n = 5:

```
1     1
2     3
3     6
4     10
5     15
```

Comment: Try something and post your code if it doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Or, in other words - copy pasting school assignment rarely get anyone to write a code for you, so you can present plagiarised code as your own.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  We're not here to write your code for you.  We'll help you if you've made a genuine effort to produce the code and can show what you're getting, what you should be getting, and the code you used to get it.  And saying "please help" 2 minutes after submitting the question is ridiculous!  After 2 hours, maybe, though even then you'd be coming across as pushy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a hint since this looks like a h/w assignment.

if you check the graphics you posted, for computing (n)th number you're just adding a new row to the (n-1)th figure at the bottom with n new dots.

starting with

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 1+2 = 3
3 -> 3+3 = 6
4 -> 6+4 = 10
```

or `f(n) = f(n-1) + n` with initial condition `f(0)=0`

Now, you can recursively solve this problem at this point.  However, we can go a step further and compute a closed form formula as well.

```
 f(1) = f(0) + 1
 f(2) = f(1) + 2
 ...
 f(n) = f(n-1) + n
+------------------
 f(n) = f(0) + 1 + 2 + ... + n = n*(n+1)/2
```

Comment: Thanks @karakfa!..i thought the question asked to print those triangles! But how would we in that case?